# Paypal System error (DCC_PREPROCESSOR_ERROR)

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using paypal in my android store, it works fine and can successfully checkout when using "Pay with Paypal". But when i try to use "Pay with Card" the error message is:

> request failure with http statusCode:400,exception:Bad Request
>
> request failed with server response:{"name":"DCC_PREPROCESSOR_ERROR","message":"DCC_PREPROCESSOR_ERROR","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#DCC_PREPROCESSOR_ERROR","debug_id":"f0ff05ade42a9"}
>   DCC_PREPROCESSOR_ERROR

Here is the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyxpn.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android SDK in PayPal is based on REST API feature and REST API in PayPal is having a limit of Credit Card features to US and UK country with Pro account. What merchant country you are used in this test?

Comment: I use Philippines as a merchant country, BTW thanks for the response!

Comment: Does this credit card feature works on live in this country?

Comment: As I mentioned, both Live and Sandbox in REST API DCC only available in US and UK country. If you try with some other country it will not work.